# Invoke MsBuild from custom task without inheriting properties and ItemGroups

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

The [Build framework](https://github.com/nbuildkit/nBuildKit.MsBuild) I'm working on provides a number of default steps so that the user only needs to provide configuration files describing their build process. The framework will then invoke the correct build steps based on the available information.

The standard approach to this is to have a top level project file that imports all the other necessary files. However this does not work because at the start of the process we don't know which imports we need so we would have to dynamically import project files when they are required. The solution to this is to create an `ItemGroup` with the file paths of the scripts to execute and then to execute them, e.g.:

```
<!-- Simplified version of the approach ... -->
<ItemGroup>
    <ThingsToBuild Include="a" />
    <ThingsToBuild Include="b" />
</ItemGroup>
<MsBuild Projects="@(ThingsToBuild)" />
```

The main problem I'm currently trying to solve is that some steps collect information that is used in later steps, e.g. version or VCS information. This information is then later on made available for template parameter replacement via an `ItemGroup`. Because these `ItemGroups` change over the course of the build process a problem arises in that MsBuild does not reload previously imported project files, so any project files with ItemGroup information will not be reloaded after they have been changed. So we can either:

1. Generate the items each time we need them from information stored somewhere. Note that sometimes the information is straight forward to obtain, e.g. file paths stored in a property, and sometimes it is more complicated, e.g. version numbers or VCS information obtained from a file.

   ```
   <PropertyGroup>
       <MyProperty>At $TIME$ the version is: $VERSION$.</MyProperty>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <Target Name="a">
       <!-- 
           Use ItemGroup if you want to add straight forward items
           and the item group is used in the same target
       -->
       <ItemGroup>
           <MyItem Include="a" />
       </ItemGroup>

       <!-- 
           Use CreateItem if you need to to nasty manipulation or
           the ItemGroup is used in another target
       -->
       <CreateItem Include="$(MyProperty.Replace(',', ';').ToLower().Split(';'))">
           <Output ItemName="MyItem" TaskParameter="Include" />
       </CreateItem>

       <!-- Use the MyItem items here -->
       <TemplateText Template="$(MyProperty)" Tokens="@(MyItem)">
           <Output PropertyName="MyTranslatedProperty" TaskParameter="Result" />
       </TemplateText>
   </Target>
   ```
2. Generate a file containing the `ItemGroup` when the information is made available and import those each time they are required

The first approach is simpler because you can just load all projects into the same instance of MsBuild. However it is also much slower because we have to generate the item groups each time we need them, which turns out to be lots of times.

Because of the way MsBuild handles project file imports the second approach requires that each build step is loaded into an independent instance of MsBuild because otherwise updated files are never reloaded.

Even with that the second approach is about four times faster than the first approach due to the large number of times we use the itemgroups.

It is however not quite fast enough and for that I want to go back to a single MsBuild instance because application loading time can be quite high depending on the hardware capabilities. However in order to make the loading of the `ItemGroups` work I will need to execute each project in it's own little 'bubble' / appdomain / *(something)*.

I have tried using the [ProjectCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.evaluation.projectcollection.aspx) and the [Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.evaluation.project.aspx) classes but apparently you can't call [Project.Build()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd234385.aspx) from inside a running build. This results in an InvalidOperationException.

So now the question is what would be the best way to 'reload' the project files containing the item groups so that each step gets the latest version and not the previously loaded version

---- EDIT ----

An example of the behaviour can be found in a [sample repository](https://github.com/pvandervelde/MsBuild.InvocationExample).

Comment: You say the second approach is 4 times faster but not fast enough. Yet you want to go back to the first approach which is already 4 times slower so even further away from 'fast enough'. That seems complicated. Anyway, I read your question a couple of times but still have no clear view of what you are trying to do. Can you someow clarify, maybe by aid of some clear examples? Also reading the last paragraph sounds like starting a seperate msbuild process really is *the* way to go. Usually the overhead of the build tools is peanuts in comparision with actual compile/link/..., no?

Comment: I'm not trying to go completely back to the first approach, more trying to find a happy medium between the first and second approaches. I'll try to add some samples or maybe link to a repo with samples. I have to admit it isn't straight forward. The overhead is not very high, but if you have many steps then it can make up a decent amount of the time, and given that I can't make the compilers any faster ...

Comment: @stijn I've updated the question and added a link to a repository containing a very basic sample of what I'm trying to achieve